# How to deploy a spring application in aws?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I host a Spring application in AWS.

I know that a Spring boot app is deployes easily with Elastic Bean Stalk. What about a Spring app? Should i migrate first to Spring boot? Or I should just run it on a Tomcat installed on an EC2?

Comment: visit documentation: You can deploy spring web application packaged in war.
https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/aws-web-app-deployment-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can build your Spring APP using Maven:

`mvn clean install -f /your/module/path`

The result will be located inside the `/your/module/path/target/` folder as a `war` package (and these packages can be read by Tomcat).

Install Tomcat on your EC2, regarding your JRE (Tomcat 8 works great until Java 10- and Tomcat 8.5+ for Java 11+).

If you are working with Java 8, you can easily install the EC2 instance by launching it with Ubuntu 16.04 (just for testing):

`apt-get install default-jdk` (will install JDK8)
`apt-get install tomcat8` (will install Tomcat 8)

Once installation is done, you can upload your `war` packages to `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/` folder and then fire the command `service tomcat8 stop|start`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have a lot of property files along with my spring application. how so i handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated AWS tutorial that uses the AWS SDK for Java V2 within a Spring Boot app. This application invokes several AWS Services. You can package up the application into a JAR and deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. For step by step instructions, see [Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project).